# C# Instances error

Tags: c#, exception, instance

so I have my Winform, in which I have a dgv with data in it, and I need to be able to save that data into two separated arraylists when the appropiate cell is clicked.
No problem with that really, but I hav which might be possibly the dumbest error to be ever programmed:
I need to instance the class where the arraylists are, "clsAL", but the programme still throws an error, arguing that the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". Here's the code (ingore anything that has nothing to do with this, specially if it's in spanish :D)

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.OleDb;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;


    namespace WindowsFormsApplication7
    {
        public partial class FormH : Form
        {
            clsAL cls;
        public FormH()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void FormH_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cls = new clsAL();
            OleDbCommand comm;
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
            DataSet dset;
            OleDbDataAdapter adap = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            OleDbCommandBuilder cmb;
            conn.ConnectionString = "Provider = 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0'; Data Source = 'RoboTIC.mdb'";
            comm = new OleDbCommand("Select * From tblHistorial", conn);
            adap = new OleDbDataAdapter(comm);
            dset = new DataSet();
            adap.Fill(dset, "tblHistorial");
            dgvHistorial.DataSource = dset.Tables["tblHistorial"];
        }

        private void dgvHistorial_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            cls = new clsAL();
            string operacion = dgvHistorial.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
            cls.dir.Clear();
            cls.time.Clear();
            string aux = "";
            for (int a = 0; a > operacion.Length; a++)
            {
                aux = aux + operacion[a];
                if (aux == "a")
                {
                    cls.dir.Add("avanzar");
                }
                if (aux == "d")
                {
                    cls.dir.Add("derecha");
                }
                if (aux == "i")
                {
                    cls.dir.Add("izquierda");
                }
                if (aux == "r")
                {
                    cls.dir.Add("retroceder");
                }
                if (aux == "/")
                { 

                }
                if (aux != "a" && aux != "a" && aux != "a" && aux != "a" && aux != "/")
                {
                    cls.time.Add(Convert.ToInt32(operacion[a]+operacion[a+1]));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is probably in the `clsAl` class. It's likely one of your arraylists in that class is not allocated at the time you try to do an operation on it. Can you post the full exception info (stack trace)?

Comment: I doubt that because I had to work with this arraylists in other forms in the same proyect and I had no problem

Comment: Alright, post 100 lines of code and not stack trace for your rudimentary error. Good luck getting help.

Comment: I agree with @evanmcdonnal.  This question is worthless without telling us where the exception occurs and a stack trace of the exception.

Comment: @user1800870: I don't know if you are aware of it but in the exception stack trace you can find the exact line of code where the exception is being thrown. That's why other comments are suggesting you post the stack trace as well.

Comment: oh yes -.- Sorry fellows, its on the "cls.dir.Clear();" line.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `dir` arraylist in `clsAl`. This is a `NullReferenceException`. It is because you haven't allocated the `dir` arraylist at the time you're trying to call `Clear()` on it.

In the constructor for `clsAl` add

```
     clsAl()
     {
          dir = new ArrayList();
          time = new ArrayList();
     }
```

and you will stop getting these exceptions.